# mysql - count the unique number of occurrences of a type of data on a given date

Tags: mysql, database

So I have 1 pivot table which has the following structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `offer_order` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `offer_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `order_id` (`order_id`,`offer_id`));
```

Following some sample data for offer_order

```
id | order_id | offer_id | created_at
---------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | 1        | 2017-04-16 00:00:00 
2  | 2        | 1        | 2017-04-16 00:00:00 
3  | 1        | 2        | 2017-04-16 00:00:00 
4  | 3        | 3        | 2017-04-17 00:00:00 
5  | 3        | 1        | 2017-04-18 00:00:00 
6  | 2        | 1        | 2017-04-18 00:00:00
```

Now data out of the above sample data that I want is

```
offer_redemption_date | no_of_unique_orders_that_day
----------------------------------------------------
2017-04-16            | 2
2017-04-17            | 1
2017-04-18            | 2
```

I tried following query to get to one stage:

```
 select date(created_at) as offer_redemption_date, order_id, count(order_id) as count from offer_order group by offer_redemption_date, order_id;
```

This gives me following result

```
offer_redemption_date|order_id|count
-------------------------------------
2017-04-16           | 1      | 2
2017-04-16           | 2      | 1
2017-04-17           | 3      | 1
2017-04-18           | 2      | 1
2017-04-18           | 3      | 1
```

Now what I am unable to do is to count the unique number of occurrences of an order_id on a given date. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` for that:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS offer_redemption_date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(order_id)) AS count
FROM offer_order
GROUP BY offer_redemption_date;
```

So here you `COUNT` the number of `DISTINCT` values for `order_id`.

Comment: As soon as I wrote the question, I recalled this query.   select date(created_at) as dated, count( distinct(order_id)) as unique_orders from offer_order group by dated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

And a different approach:

```
select created_at as offer_redemption_date, count(*) as no_of_unique_orders_that_day
 from (
 select count(*) cnt, order_id, created_at
 from `offer_order`
 group by order_id, created_at
 ) x 
 group by created_at
```

The derived table approach is not as elegant as the `COUNT DISTINCT` solution, but it can be very helpful in other situations, where such a shortcut does not exist.